# How to install Mongodb in a docker container and use it?

Tags: server, 22.04, docker, mongodb

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, as of Oct 2022 ubuntu 22.04 is not supported by Mongodb team completely, So I'm struggling with it as I need `mongodb-org` installed for my work. So my question is, Is there anyway I can install mongodb in a docker container and use it???
I don't know much about docker if anyone knows how can I achieve this that will be really appreciated.

Comment: Yes, you can. Mongo has [an official Docker repository](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo) that you can pull images from. If you are running Ubuntu Desktop, then you can [follow these instructions](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/) to install everything you need 

Answer (score 0):

If you have Docker installed, run the following to start a MongoDB server:

```
docker run -d --name MongoDB -p 27017:27017 mongo:latest
```

Mapping the port will allow you to use the MongoDB port directly on the host IP.

It's also possible to start a stack with Mongo Express. Create the following `mongo-stack.yml`

```
# Use root/example as user/password credentials
version: '3.1'

services:

  mongo:
    image: mongo:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example

  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: root
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: example
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL: mongodb://root:example@mongo:27017/
```

Then run `docker compose -f mongo-stack.yml up -d`

You can also choose fixed versions instead of `latest`.

Visit the [official Docker page](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo) to see more configuration options.

Comment: you will need a volume for your database data. add 
`volumes:
      -<your_local_db_data_directory>:/data/db`